# How can i pass the multiple parameter value as request from axios to laravel

Tags: reactjs, laravel

This is the API code to send the request. It works fine when I send it with only one parameter.

```
const handlecreate=(evt)=>{
      evt.preventDefault();
      const fd = new FormData();
      fd.append('image', picture);
 
      axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/post/store',{fd,form});
   )
}
```

In laravel as backend:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'image' => 'required',
        'category'=>'required',
        'slug'=>'required',
        'heading'=>'required',
    ]);
 
    if ($validator->fails())
    {
        return response(['errors'=>$validator->errors()->all()], 200);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post the code you tried with multiple parameters. Also, do you mean multiple files/images?

Comment: when i send form text data and images which is store in different state hooks  i got validation error second one parameter is not act as a request

Comment: check this [tutorial](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/laravel-multiple-files-images-upload/). Scroll down to "Controller with Validation" you'll see the foreach().

Comment: iam using api react.js axios works for only one parameter  value of another paramter remain undefiend

Comment: can you show console.log of the data you were passing?

Comment: @vimkndll, share your api route in the laravel so it would be more easier to identify, anyhow I will answer this question based on assumption below.

Answer (score 0):

If we want to post the data with multiple parameter that is store in different state hooks then we have to append the each data of hooks

const handlecreate=(evt)=>{

const fd = new FormData();

fd.append('image', picture);

fd.append('heading',form.heading);

axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/post/store',fd);

}

Answer (score 0):

I would be answering the question in bit depth, so that it can help other as well with thorough understanding.

**Note**: Make sure you removed the cross origin issues if you are using react as front end or any other framework

---

**Backend work**

First you need to make the route properly in your laravel api located in laravel: **routes/api**

Let's assume we created the route in the api file and connected our controller likewise:

```
Route::post('/storeData', 'StoreController@store');
```

---

Now we need a controller on the **same name** in:

> App/http/controllers/StoreController

In the **StoreController** we need the function which is connected that is **store function in the StoreController**:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {


        $this->validate($request, [

            'vin' => 'required|unique:autos,vin',
            'lot' => 'required|unique:autos,lot',

        ]);

       
        $autos = new Auto; //this is the model(mvc)
      
        $autos->vin = $request->vin;
        $autos->lot = $request->lot;
      
           $autos->save();

    return response()->json([
       'success_message' => 'success auto is created',
   ], 200); // a message to the front end after successful execution of the query

}
```

**Frontend Work**

```
 export const storeData = () => {
      let axiosConfig = {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
          Accept: "application/json",
          Authorization: `Bearer ${decryptedToken}`, // if you had made the passport 0Auth2
        }
   
      };

    const autoData = new FormData();
    autoData.append("vin", autoData.vin);
    autoData.append("lot", autoData.lot);
      axios
        .post(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/autoDataStore`, autoData, axiosConfig)
        .then((response) => {
          if (response.data.success_message) {
            console.log(response.data);
          } else if(response.data.error_message){
  
          }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err.response.data.errors)
        });
    };
```